# provide alternative api to Python class via property-like redirection

Tags: python, pandas, oop, design-patterns

This is a general Python design question, but to be specific I'll be talking about `pandas.DataFrame` class and its `unstack` method.

My goal is to provide an alternative version of `unstack`, however I don't want to override the original version, rather provide a way to access my version via `.x` redirection layer:

```
import pandas as pd
dat = pd.DataFrame(some args)
# call my function
dat.x.unstack()
# call original function
dat.unstack()
```

A design requirement is that the implementation of my version should be able to call the original `unstack`.

For the sake of this question one can assume I'm allowed to add a little bit of code to pandas.DataFrame, but that addition should be minimal given it's a public package.
A fully non-intrusive solution would be a plus.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have a class called `X` that has all the additional methods you want to implement on top of `DataFrame` that looks something like:

```
class X(object):

    def __init__(self, df):
        self._df = df

    def unstack(self):
        return 'X.untrack called!'
```

You could create a wrapper around `DataFrame` like this:

```
class DataFrameWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._dataframe = pd.DataFrame(*args, **kwargs)
        self._delegate = X(self._dataframe)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr == 'x':
            return self._delegate
        return getattr(self._dataframe, attr)

dfw = DataFrameWrapper([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(dfw.unstack())    # Normal unstack() output
print(dfw.x.unstack())  # X.untrack called!
```

You could also use `setattr` to set the attribute `x` on your `DataFrame` instance to reference an instance of your delegate object.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
setattr(df, 'x', X())
print(df.unstack())    # Normal unstack() output
print(df.x.unstack())  # X.untrack called!
```

EDIT: Passed the dataframe in the wrapper to `X`s constructor.

Comment: Just updated but you could just pass the dataframe constructed in the wrapper to Xs constructor. That way x still has access to dataframe methods and state. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a cyclical dependency here that would hinder garbage collection:
df -> x -> df

Comment: This is not a cyclical dependency since the dataframe does not reference the wrapper or x and x does not reference the wrapper. This should not cause any issues with garbage collection.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I was referring to the second part of your answer: "You could also use `setattr` to set the attribute `x` on your `DataFrame` instance to reference an instance of your delegate object". In this case the `DataFrame` references the wrapper via property `x` which, in turn, references the `DataFrame` via property `_df`.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Ahh thanks for clarifying yes you are correct that would be a cyclic reference and you might need a different solution. That's a good observation!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution inspired by @kingkupps use of **getattr** in his answer.

```
import pandas as pd


class DataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    # replace pd.DataFrame.__getattr__
    _super__getattr__ = pd.DataFrame.__getattr__

    def _replacement__getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'x':
            return DataFrame(self)
        return DataFrame._super__getattr__(self, name)

    pd.DataFrame.__getattr__ = _replacement__getattr__

    # new api
    def unstack(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('new api')
        return super().unstack(*args, **kwargs)


df = pd.DataFrame(range(5))
print(df.unstack())
print(df.x.unstack())
```

EDIT: it turned out pandas explicitly provides a way to define such extensions, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html